# Scala - escaping dollar sign in raw string interpolated regex

Tags: scala

How are dollar signs escaped in raw string interpolated order to match against them using Scala regex lib?

Compilation error: `val regex: Regex = raw"""\$""".r`

Answer (score 1):

`val dollarSignRegex1 = raw"""\$$""".r`

Comment: These do not compile to the same regex.

Comment: @jwvh You're right, the first one actually doesn't work. Removing it for another option

Comment: What example `String` are you matching against? It looks to me like `"\\$".r` is all you need.

Comment: @jwvh Yes, this is only valid for raw string interpolation. Should put that in the question. Thanks